# How to cast lambda method parameters?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a lambda expression like below. What I want to ask is Is there any easy way or best practice for casting method parameter?

```
        results.forEach(
            (result) ->
            {
                ((JSONObject)result).put("test", "test"); 
                ((JSONObject)result).put("time", System.currentTimeMillis());  
                otherList.add(((JSONObject)result));
            }
    );
```

When I try to change input type like

```
(JSONObject result) ->
```

I am getting below error;

```
incompatible types: Consumer<JSONObject> cannot be converted to Consumer<? super Object>
```

Comment: As the message says, those types aren't compatible.  Why not just introduce a local variable?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth At first I thought that (creating a new local variable) but What if I have 5-6 inputs? Do I need to create a new variable for all of them?

Comment: This problem is not unique to lambdas - it applies to any method.  (That said, if you have a lambda with 5-6 inputs, something weird is probably going on!)

Comment: Just parametrize the list correctly: Use `List<JSONObject>` instead of `List` or `List<Object>` and this isn't a problem...

Comment: If for whatever reason you can’t type the list correctly, you can use: `results.stream().map(JSONObject.class::cast).forEach((JSONObject result)->{ … });`. In the standard Java API, there are no scenarios with more than two parameters…

Comment: @Holger, help me understand...I thought that the problem was with the JSONObject type not being castable to the type of the list. Would casting the stream type as you show make JSONObject castable to the list type?

Answer (score 4):

The error message explains to you that your list technically–from the compiler's perspective–may contain elements that are not of class `JSONObject`. Thus you cannot use a `Consumer<JSONObject>` here. The lambda `(JSONObject result) -> ...` actually *is* such an incompatible consumer.

Assuming you have no control over the element type of `results` you might just map your elements to the correct type before consuming them. In case you expect anything other than only `JSONObject` elements, you might use the `filter()` method to omit all incompatible elements and only process the `JSONObject` instances.

```
results.filter(JSONObject.class::isInstance) // only needed if you expect non JSONObject elements, too
       .map(result -> (JSONObject) result)
       .forEach(result -> {
         result.put("test", "test"); 
         result.put("time", System.currentTimeMillis());  
         otherList.add(((JSONObject)result));
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Fabian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991525/fabian) suggested under the comments, you might have initialized your `results` like `List` or `List<Object>`

What you can do is, you can have `List<JSONObject>`

```
results.forEach(
            (result) ->
            {
                result.put("test", "test"); 
                result.put("time", System.currentTimeMillis());  
                otherList.add(result);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use stream functions in a manner like this to typecast at one step and then query in the subsequent step-

```
    List<String> collect = Lists.newArrayList(obj.get("graph").getAsJsonObject().get("nodes").getAsJsonArray()).stream().
                map(x -> (JsonObject) x).
                map(x -> {
                    String res = "";
                    try {
                        res = CommonUtils.getAsString(x,"modelKey");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    return res;
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: This kind of code defeats the hole purpose of type-safety in Java